# Shell script to add or replace block of text?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, regular-expression

I'm looking for a shell script (Bash) that adds or replaces copyright text at the beginning of the file (for `.c` and `.h` files).

It should search and add or replace the copyright text block for all the `.c` and `.h` files from the parent directory where I execute my script.

Existing copyright text:

```
            /* --------------------------------------------------
                Copyright 2014 Author name

                All rights reserved
             ----------------------------------------------------*/
```

New Copyright text.

```
             /* Copy right text bla bla bla
              * some license text bla bla bla
              * All rights reserved xyz xyz */
```

**Note**

1. Copyright text should be added at the beginning of the file (`.c` and `.h`) only and always the existing copyright text will be in the beginning of the file.
2. It should search and add or replace for all the `.c` and `.h` files within the parent directories and sub directories.

**EDIT**

This is what I tried:

```
      for file in `find . -type f -name "*.h"`
       do
       echo $file
       if grep -qRin "                            ----------------------------------------------------------------------\*\/" $file
        then
       echo "Replaced License Text"
         sed '1,/^ ----------------------------------------------------------------------\*\/$/d' < $file | cat licence_file - > $file.new
       mv $file.new $file
      else
    cat licence_file $file >$file.new && mv $file.new $file
     echo "Added License Test"
     fi
      done
```

Licence_file contains my new license text.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107309/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-copyright-license-headers-in-my-source-files

Comment: @jasonwryan : Edited the question. It works fine but the problem is it removes all the content from the matched text to beginning of the file.So if there is any code before the license text it will get removed :(

Answer (score 2):

`ed` is 'the standard text editor'. It's not really ideal to use for day-to-day editing, but it is [readily scriptable](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed).

```
ed file.c <<'EOF'
1,/\*\//d
i
/* Copy right text bla bla bla
 * some license text bla bla bla
 * All rights reserved xyz xyz */
.
w
q
EOF
```

The first command deletes from the first line, up to and including the first line containing a `*/` (both the `*` and the `/` need to be escaped). The second command is a simple insert -- the `i` tells `ed` to enter 'insert' mode, while a `.` on its own tells `ed` to exit insert mode. `w` means 'write', and saves the file; `q` means 'quit'. The whole thing is within a 'here-document', which begins and ends with an `EOF` (this is arbitrary; you can use any string you want).

This can easily enough be used in a loop:

```
for f in ./*.{c,h}; do ed "$f" <<'EOF'
1,/\*\//d
i
/* Copy right text bla bla bla
 * some license text bla bla bla
 * All rights reserved xyz xyz */
.
w
q
EOF
done
```

If you want recursiveness (i.e. to work in subdirectories), either use `shopt -s globstar` and use `./**/*.{c,h}` in the above command, or use `find` and a while loop:

```
find . -name '*.c' -name '*.h' -print0 | while read -d '' f; do ed "$f" <<'EOF'
1,/\*\//d
i
/* Copy right text bla bla bla
 * some license text bla bla bla
 * All rights reserved xyz xyz */
.
w
q
EOF
done
```

If you might do this many times, it might be worth putting it in a script.

```
#!/bin/sh
ed "$1" <<'EOF'
1,/\*\//d
i
/* Copy right text bla bla bla
 * some license text bla bla bla
 * All rights reserved xyz xyz */
.
w
q
EOF
```

If you name this something like copyright.sh, drop it in somewhere in your $PATH, and make it executable, then you can simply:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/*.{c,h}; do copyright.sh "$f"; done
```

Comment: The 'r' read command is useful.  ```ed config.inc.php <<'EOF'
/mysecrettoken/
.,+1d
.-1r token.txt
w
q
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

A little messy, but this python will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]
fo=open(filename,'r+')
fr=fo.read()
frs=fr.replace('/* --------------------------------------------------\n                Copyright 2014 Author name\n\n                All rights reserved\n             ----------------------------------------------------*/','/* Copy right text bla bla bla\n* some license text bla bla bla\n* All rights reserved xyz xyz */')
fo.seek(0,0)
fo.write(frs)
fo.close()
```

This works if the original text and replacement text are **exactly** in the same format(including the hyphen lines) as given in the question. Call this python from the directory where the files exist using:

`for i in ./{*.c,*.h} ; do python <scriptname.py> $i ; done`

How it works:

Straightforward. It just opens the files, and replaces the lines given between the first couple of single-quotes in the `frs=fr.replace....` line with the lines given in the second couple of single-quotes given in the same line.