# Popular/historical tools for managing license headers in source code?

Tags: utilities, licenses

I've never been in the need of adding/updating/replacing license headers into every source code file in a big project, but now I am. And I always thought there was some popular tool for doing it, because many historical source tarballs have license headers in all their files together with the typical version header applied by the (then popular) RCS/SCCS version control systems.

I mean, just look at big sources published in the 90s by SGI, HP, Berkeley, etc, and it's there. I always thought that was automated, and not only for adding the license notice, but for updating/replacing/removing it.

But I searched and searched, and found no such tool. There are some tools for doing this at GitHub, but they are pretty recent... nothing with a >20-year tradition.

Did all the companies from the commercial UNIX era use their own unpublished in-house shell scripts for doing this? Wasn't there any popular tool for this in those years?

Comment: Related: [Shell script to add or replace block of text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171617/shell-script-to-add-or-replace-block-of-text)

Comment: Likely those were in fact unpublished scripts, which usually simply replaced existing notices and dates with "updated" ones (I've actually written tools which do it right -- unpublished -- but see [this](https://invisible-island.net/personal/copyrights.html) for comments on the *usual* case).

Comment: @ThomasDickey I didn't know about your `copyrite` tool, and I really like it. The PDF manpage at the website, however, mentions it can only process 7bit chars, while some of my sources are UTF8-encoded. Do you think I could easily move the 1-bit mask out of the text data, so that UTF8-encoded files can be processed, or would it imply to perform great changes into the code?

Comment: I think it would take a lot of work (I haven't tried).

Comment: Do you have something in mind like the `%sccs.include.file%` festure that has  been added to `SCCS get` by Keith Bostic in 1990 to `BSD`? ... or rather shell scripts that everybody writes to set up unified license headers if the version control does not have such a feature?

Comment: @schily: actually I didn't have anything in mind, but wondering how they used to do this when maintaining large source code trees in the 90s. For example, when you downloaded sources from SGI, all files included its legal notice, and I suppose this was automated.

Comment: @cesss Solaris did have the Copyright notices verbose in all source files. When OpenSolaris has been published on June 14, 2005, all files have been edited to add the CDDL headers.

Comment: @schily ...do you mean they edited all files manually? (if affirmative, wow!)

Comment: @cesss it is unlikely that they did this manually for 60000 files. I guess they did use `awk` or something smilar. BTW: for the same reason, they introduced a program called `cw` in 2004, when the Sun compiler was too late for x86 64 bit support and they had to use a hacked gcc (gcc was not fully ready too). The program `cw` translates SunPro compiler options into gcc options and this prevented Sun from editing 8000 makefiles manually.